# Grouping when a key with same name exists at different levels using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following input xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <results>
      <case>
         <KEY>c1</KEY>
         <issue>
            <KEY>i1</KEY>
            <id>Apple</id>
         </issue>
         <issue>
            <KEY>i1</KEY>
            <id>Orange</id>
         </issue>
         <issue>
            <KEY>i2</KEY>
            <id>Mango</id>
         </issue>
      </case>
      <case>
         <KEY>c1</KEY>
         <issue>
            <KEY>i5</KEY>
            <id>Apricot</id>
         </issue>
         <issue>
            <KEY>i5</KEY>
            <id>Blueberry</id>
         </issue>
         <issue>
            <KEY>i6</KEY>
            <id>blackberry</id>
         </issue>
      </case>
      <case>
         <KEY>c2</KEY>
         <issue>
            <KEY>i3</KEY>
            <id>Banana</id>
         </issue>
         <issue>
            <KEY>i3</KEY>
            <id>Cherry</id>
         </issue>
         <issue>
            <KEY>i4</KEY>
            <id>Grapes</id>
         </issue>
      </case>
   </results>
</root>
```

Now I want to group by `<KEY>` of `<case>` first and then by`<KEY>` of `<issue>`. The idea is to group all the `<issue>`'s by their issue key and case key.  Finally I want to move all the `<id>`'s whose issue keys are same under `<sourceInstance>` node within the `<issue>`.

My output xml should be as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <results>
      <case>
         <KEY>c1</KEY>
         <issue>
            <KEY>i1</KEY>
            <sources>
               <sourceInstance>
                  <id>Apple</id>
               </sourceInstance>
               <sourceInstance>
                  <id>Orange</id>
               </sourceInstance>
            </sources>
         </issue>
         <issue>
            <KEY>i2</KEY>
            <sources>
               <sourceInstance>
                  <id>Mango</id>
               </sourceInstance>
            </sources>
         </issue>
         <issue>
            <KEY>i5</KEY>
            <sources>
               <sourceInstance>
                  <id>Apricot</id>
               </sourceInstance>
               <sourceInstance>
                  <id>Blueberry</id>
               </sourceInstance>
            </sources>
         </issue>
         <issue>
            <KEY>i6</KEY>
            <sources>
               <sourceInstance>
                  <id>Apple</id>
               </sourceInstance>
               <sourceInstance>
                  <id>Orange</id>
               </sourceInstance>
            </sources>
         </issue>
      </case>
      <case>
         <KEY>c2</KEY>
         <issue>
            <KEY>i3</KEY>
            <sources>
               <sourceInstance>
                  <id>Banana</id>
               </sourceInstance>
               <sourceInstance>
                  <id>Cherry</id>
               </sourceInstance>
            </sources>
         </issue>
         <issue>
            <KEY>i4</KEY>
            <sources>
               <sourceInstance>
                  <id>Grapes</id>
               </sourceInstance>
            </sources>
         </issue>
      </case>
   </results>
</root>
```

I have tried by using the following XSLT, but couldn't get the desired xml output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:key name="case" match="case" use="string(KEY)" />
   <xsl:key name="issue" match="case" use="concat(KEY, '|', KEY)" />
   <xsl:template match="results">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="case[generate-id() = generate-id(key('case', string(KEY))[1])]" mode="case" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="case" mode="case">
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="KEY">
            <case>
               <xsl:copy-of select="KEY" />
               <xsl:apply-templates select="key('case', KEY)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('issue', concat(KEY, '|', KEY))[1])]" mode="issue" />
            </case>
         </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="case " mode="issue">
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="KEY">
            <issue>
               <xsl:copy-of select="KEY" />
               <sources>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="key('issue', id)" />
               </sources>
            </issue>
         </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="case">
      <sourceInstance>
         <id>
            <xsl:value-of select="id" />
         </id>
      </sourceInstance>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It appears that I am unable to frame the correct combination of a key using the `<KEY>` of `<case>` and `<issue>` as the node with the same name (i.e.`<KEY>` )exists at both the places.

Can somebody tell me what I am missing in my XSLT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is the definition of your key of `issue`

```
<xsl:key name="issue" match="case" use="concat(KEY, '|', KEY)" />
```

You need to be matching `issue` elements here, and using a concatenation of the KEY for `issue` and the parent `case` element

```
<xsl:key name="issue" match="issue" use="concat(KEY, '|', ../KEY)" />
```

Then, to get the grouped `issue` elements for a given `case` KEY, you would do this...

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('case', KEY)/issue[generate-id() = generate-id(key('issue', concat(KEY, '|', ../KEY))[1])]" mode="issue" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:key name="case" match="case" use="string(KEY)" />
   <xsl:key name="issue" match="issue" use="concat(KEY, '|', ../KEY)" />

   <xsl:template match="results">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="case[generate-id() = generate-id(key('case', string(KEY))[1])]" mode="case" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="case" mode="case">
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="KEY">
            <case>
               <xsl:copy-of select="KEY" />
               <xsl:apply-templates select="key('case', KEY)/issue[generate-id() = generate-id(key('issue', concat(KEY, '|', ../KEY))[1])]" mode="issue" />
            </case>
         </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="issue" mode="issue">
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="KEY">
            <issue>
               <xsl:copy-of select="KEY" />
               <sources>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="key('issue', concat(KEY, '|', ../KEY))" />
               </sources>
            </issue>
         </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="issue">
      <sourceInstance>
         <id>
            <xsl:value-of select="id" />
         </id>
      </sourceInstance>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That's perfect!  +1 for your quick response.